Get ID ranges for multiple sections
How do I get the lower- and upper-bound range(s) of the following data for each set of "1s":



LogFileTextID
ErrorLineFlag




88182351
0


88182352
0


88182353
0


88182354
0


88182355
1


88182356
1


88182357
0


88182358
1


88182359
1


88182360
1


88182361
1


88182362
1


88182363
1


88182364
1


88182365
1


88182366
1


88182367
1


88182368
1


88182369
1


88182370
1


88182371
1


88182372
1


88182373
0


88182374
0


88182375
0


88182376
0


88182377
0


88182378
0


88182379
0


88182380
0



I am expecting the following:



InstanceNum
LowerID
UpperID




1
88182351



2
88182352



3
88182353



4
88182354



5
88182355
88182356


6
88182357



7
88182358
88182372


8
88182373



9
88182374



10
88182375



11
88182376



12
88182377



13
88182378



14
88182379



15
88182380




Is this possible?

Yes, look into gaps and islands, there are plenty of solutions

What are you really asking here. "Is this possible?" Just results in a yes or no answer. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What about the research you did didn't you understand?

There are so many variations of gaps-and-islands (many with complex conditions), that it is hard to pick out an appropriate answer that the OP can adapt.  This answer is one of the simpler ones that I believe can be easily modified. The key is defining the gap condition. For the above, I believe a gap occurs when either the prior (lagged) or current ErrorLineFlag is zero. If both are one, we want to group the rows.  Other defining conditions are the partitioning (none for this case) and the order (LogFileTextID here). i-nGDl6e

CREATE TABLE your_table (
  id   INT, 
  flag INT
) 

INSERT INTO
  your_table
VALUES
  ( 1, 0),
  ( 2, 0),
  ( 3, 1),
  ( 4, 0),
  ( 5, 1),
  ( 6, 0),
  ( 7, 0),
  ( 8, 1),
  ( 9, 1),
  (10, 0),
  (11, 0),
  (12, 0),
  (13, 1),
  (14, 1),
  (15, 1),
  (16, 0),
  (17, 0),
  (18, 1),
  (19, 1)

WITH
  look_behind AS
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    CASE
      WHEN flag = 0                         THEN 1
      WHEN LAG(flag) OVER (ORDER BY id) = 1 THEN 0
                                            ELSE flag
    END
      AS new_group
  FROM
    your_table 
),
  partitioned AS
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    SUM(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS group_id
  FROM
    look_behind
)
--SELECT * FROM partitioned
SELECT
  group_id,
  MIN(id)     AS min_id,
  MAX(id)     AS max_id,
  MAX(flag)   AS group_type
FROM
  partitioned
GROUP BY 
  group_id
ORDER BY
  1




group_id
min_id
max_id
group_type




1
1
1
0


2
2
2
0


3
3
3
1


4
4
4
0


5
5
5
1


6
6
6
0


7
7
7
0


8
8
9
1


9
10
10
0


10
11
11
0


11
12
12
0


12
13
15
1


13
16
16
0


14
17
17
0


15
18
19
1



fiddle

A good answer includes an explanation.
